# Format a string to a currency with negative currency like $(10.00)

Tags: c#, .net, string-formatting, currency-formatting

I need to format a negative currency as follow: `$(10.00)`

I tried to use `string.Format("{0:C}", itemprice)` but that gives me this result `($10.00)` (the $ inside the parenthesis

i also tried

```
string fmt = "##;(##)";
itemprice.ToString(fmt);
```

but it gives me the same as before `($10.00)`

Any idea on how to get a result like this: `$(10.00)`.

Comment: Why do you need the currency symbol outside the parenthesis? I would argue that negative currency _should_ be in the parenthesis, symbol and all.

Comment: +1 Oded, I totally agree, the correct format/behavior would be sign inside the parentheses.

Comment: Well yeah I know. but requests are requests. can't argue with the client :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```cs
itemPrice.ToString(@"$#,##0.00;$\(#,##0.00\)");
```

Should work. I just tested it on PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\Jcl> $teststring = "{0:$#,##0.00;$\(#,##0.00\)}"
PS C:\Users\Jcl> $teststring -f 2 
$2,00
PS C:\Users\Jcl> $teststring -f -2
$(2,00)
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: @jck how do you run this test without c# ? csc.exe.... what is PS ? can i use it to test c# expressions ? can you give me a download link ?

Comment: @Royi: PS is Powershell. For Windows XP try [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929), Vista and 7 already have Powershell built in if I remember correctly `(All Programs -> Accesories -> Windows Powershell)` I believe.

Comment: I'm getting an error about the '\' unrecognized escape characters. any idea?

Comment: Sorry, you should use a verbatim string (add @ in front of it). I've updated the sample (I also changed it to `ToString`, since `toString` [lowercase t] was invalid)

Comment: @Royi: No, Powershell won't run C# commands. `$teststring -f 2` is *not* a C# command or statement at all. You can read more about Powershell [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835506.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use Jcl's solution and make it a nice extension:

```
public static string ToMoney(this object o)
{
    return o.toString("$#,##0.00;$\(#,##0.00\)");
}
```

Then just call it:

```
string x = itemPrice.ToMoney();
```

Or another very simple implementation:

```
public static string ToMoney(this object o)
{
    // note: this is obviously only good for USD
    return string.Forma("{0:C}", o).Replace("($","$(");
}
```

Comment: Second snippet doesn't respect other currencies, i.e. hard-codes US dollar sign.

Comment: You can use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` for the `Replace` parameters

Answer (score 2):

You would have to manually split this up, since it is a non-standard formatting.

```
string.Format("{0}{1:n2}", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, itemprice);
```